# How to link the row selected in picker view from app delegate to a variable in view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uipickerview, picker

i have a questions regarding the UIPickerView. i have this method running in the the app delegate:

```objc
- (id) init {
    if([super init] == nil) return nil;
    myGoal = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              @"Select Goal",@"First Class Honors",@"Second Class, Upper",@"Second Class, Lower", @"Third Class Honors", @"Pass with Merit, Bachelor",@"Pass, Bachelor", nil];
    return self;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"picked row: %i, component: %i", row, component);
    NSLog(@"the value: %@", [self.myGoal objectAtIndex:row]);
```

and in the viewcontroller.m file, i have a IBAction linked to do a calculation when pressed. but in order to do the calculation i need to be able to know which row is selected in the app delegate's method.

in my IBAction:

```objc
- (IBAction) calculateGoal: (id) sender {

    **//--i want to link the selected pickerview row to a fix integer in his case the GPA. how sould i do this?** 
    if (row == 1) {
        double selectedGPA = 4.5;
    }
    if (row == 2) {
        double selectedGPA = 4.0;
    }
    if (row == 3) {
        double selectedGPA = 3.5;
    }
    if (row == 4) {
        double selectedGPA = 3.0;
    }
    if (row == 5) {
        double selectedGPA = 2.5;
    }
    if (row == 6) {
        double selectedGPA = 2.0;
    }

    //--change text to numbers
    double gpa = [txtGPA.text doubleValue];
    double totalau = [txtTotalAU.text doubleValue];
    double remainingau = [txtRemainingAU.text doubleValue];
    double x = gpa * totalau;
    double gpagoal = (selectedGPA * (totalau + remainingau) - x)/remainingau; //should replace 3.5 with a variable(selectedGPA) related with goal. First Class = 4.5 Second Class Upper = 4.0, Second Class Lower = 3.5, Third Class = 3.0, Pass with Merit = 2.5, Pass =2.0
```

Question:
1.in my view controller.m's IBAction, i want to be able to pull out which row the picker(a method from app delegate.m file) is currently selected so that i can assign the corresponding value to a variable "selectedGPA".

2.is my if statement in the app delegate's IBAction method correct in filtering out the row selected and assigning the integer to the variable "selectedGPA"?

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate. Set the AppDelegate to be your UIPickerView's delegate.

```
self.picker.delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to this iOS programming and this is my very first application that i am writing. could you specify where i should insert this line of code exactly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve my problem. i am not sure if this is the right way or i am just lucky it worked..

```
int row;
double selectedGPA;

row = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

//--i want to link the selected pickerview row to a fix integer in his case the GPA. how sould i do this.
if(row == 0){
    selectedGPA = 0;
}
else if (row == 1) {
    selectedGPA = 4.5;
}
else if (row == 2) {
    selectedGPA = 4.0;
}
else if (row == 3) {
    selectedGPA = 3.5;
}
else if (row == 4) {
    selectedGPA = 3.0;
}
else if (row == 5) {
    selectedGPA = 2.5;
}
else
    selectedGPA = 2.0;
```